# Helper / intermediate class has no columns in database (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

First off, I'm new to the Entity Framework and am migrating an existing project from a database framework that I wrote myself so I have a fair amount of flexibility in the solution I choose.

From what I've researched so far everything appears to be set up correctly. However, when my database is constructed, the table for a helper class I wrote has no columns in it (outside of its primary key). The most simplified version of the classes are included below with their relationships defined in the fluent API.

**Classes**

```
public class Concept
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true), MaxLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Concept Concept { get; set; }
}

public class Helper
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Content Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Tag> Instances { get; set; }

    // Helper functionality
}

public class Content
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Helper Helper { get; set; }

    public Content() { Helper = new Helper() { Subject = this }; }
}
```

**Context**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.Concept);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.Subject);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Helper>()
         .HasRequired(t => t.Subject)
         .WithRequiredDependent(c => c.Helper);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Helper>()
         .HasMany(t => t.Instances);

     modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
         .HasRequired(c => c.Helper)
         .WithRequiredPrincipal();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Content content = null;
    using (var context = new Context())
    {
        content = context.Content.Find(1);
        if (content == null)
        {
            content = new Content();

            context.Content.Add(content);
            context.Helper.Add(content.Helper);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that when the data is saved, the Helper is assigned an ID but on loading the parent class (Content) the second time around, the Helper is not lazy loaded as I would expect from the 'virtual' keyword. I suspect that this is caused by the same issue causing the absence of data in the table.

I have tried both the data annotation and fluent API approaches that EF provides but it seems that there is something fundamental that I am misunderstanding. I would like to retain this helper class as it helps organize the code far better.

As I have spent a fair amount of time researching these relationships / APIs, and scouring Google / SO without found anything to solve this issue in particular any help would be greatly appreciated!

## Updated: Solution

Thanks to a question in the comments, I realized that I was expecting to see the keys of a many-to-many relationship in the tables for the entity types themselves (i.e. in the Helpers table). However, in a many-to-many relationship, the keys will always be placed in a separate table (concatenation of type names) which was not being previously created.

By adding '.WithMany();' to the Helper section of the OnModelCreating function as below

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Helper>()
             .HasMany(t => t.Instances)
             .WithMany();
```

the many-to-many relationship became properly defined and the HelperTags table generated as expected. This is due to the fact that the many-to-many relationship is one way (Helpers always refer to Tags, Tags never refer to Helpers). This is also why the 'WithMany' does not have any arguments (since no Helper properties exist in the Tag class). Fixing this simple oversight solved the problem!

Comment: What fields are you expecting to be in Helper that aren't there? The only field I see defined is the primary key, with two other entities having foreign keys into Helper...

Comment: Yes, you make a good point... I expected to see the FK defined back to the Content class and *sigh* a list of tags- wait, that makes no sense! The 'Tag' entities are not supposed to be 'owned' by the Helper... instead of a one-to-many I was trying to make a many-to-many relationship. This is pointing me in the right direction. I just need to consider where the 'one-to-many' is being enforced. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: In my experience, EF has problems with one:one keys (where neither side is optional), but otherwise, you can make things much easier if you explicitly include the primitive key fields in your entities where you expect to see them. It will almost always figure it out with no modelBuilder goofiness needed. You just need to follow the default naming convention rules and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading:

- [Entity Framework Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx)

> **relationship Convention**
>
> In addition to navigation properties, we recommend that you include
>   foreign key properties on the types that represent dependent objects.
>
> Any property with the same data type as the principal primary key
>   property and with a name that follows one of the following formats
>   represents a foreign key for the relationship:
>
> - `<navigation property name><principal primary key property name>`
> - `<principal class name><primary key property name>`
> - `<principal primary key property name>`
>
> If multiple matches are found then precedence is given in the order
>   listed above.
>
> Foreign key detection is not case sensitive.

**Sample Code from MSDN:**

In the following example the navigation properties and a foreign key are used to define the relationship between the Department and Course classes.

```
public class Department 
{ 
    // Primary key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 

    // Navigation property 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
} 

public class Course 
{ 
    // Primary key 
    public int CourseID { get; set; } 

    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public int Credits { get; set; } 

    // Foreign key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 

    // Navigation properties 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I have had a chance to read that article and a couple of similar ones on MSDN but thanks for the suggestion! While the foreign keys are defined in the code above, I'm trying to avoid that by leveraging data annotations or fluent API if possible. Based on some of the comments so far it appears my issue stems from a many-to-many relationship being confused for a one-to-many. However, I'll definitely keep this approach in mind as well.

Comment: if you let EF create the foreign key fields for you, they're going to have stupid names with underscores in them. You really are better off doing it yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably working harder than you need to in the on ModelCreate.  You should probably redesign your classes use Identifiers, like this:

```
public class Tag
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long SubjectId { get; set; }
    public long ConceptId { get; set; }

    public virtual Content Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Concept Concept { get; set; }
}
```

You need to keep the ID names the EXACT same as the object names + Id and EF will magically link everything up.  If you don't want them required then make the id nullable (C# 6 == `long? SubjectId`).

Also, I have changed the ID -> Id; I have no idea if this matters. At one point I remember having to do that to get things working (it was YEARS ago) and I have been doing it that way ever since.

Comment: I don't *think* case matters but I always stick to `Id` as well. Also, there's *some* leeway in the foreign key field names, but the alternatives are almost always dumber looking that `ReferenceFieldId` so I'd also agree with your choice there :)

Comment: Yeah, it's just a preference thing- I was trying to simplify the class structure by defining the entity relationships via data annotations. Then I moved to the fluent API since it's marginally more versatile. I'll definitely keep this suggestion in mind if other solutions don't work. Re: ID / Id / id , it looks like EF is now case insensitive (and you can have the ID on its own or with the type prepended): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx. It's in the section on 'Primary Key Convention'